# Как можно прибавить все значения из массива С#?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Хорошего всем времени суток, заранее спасибо <3. Вот в чём суть. Я хочу создать регенерацию параметров с разными бонусами. Пока кода нету то напишу здесь в чём дело. Я хочу в переменную "Конечный реген" прибавлять "Базовый реген" + "Бонусный реген персонажа" + **"Все регены от предметов"** <=== вот в этом суть, эта переменная у меня является массивом float, при покупке предмета который даёт ману, я хочу отдельной переменной засунуть в массив. Так как неизвестно сколько будет в каком то этапе игры количество предметов с мана-регеном.
Так вот **===>Как можно прибавить все значения из массива?<===** Что бы как

> "Конечный реген" = "Базовый реген" + "Бонусный реген персонажа" + "Все
> регены от предметов"[]

Либо что бы как то засунуть в переменную результат прибавления из массива

Comment: `"Конечный реген" = "Базовый реген" + "Бонусный реген персонажа" + "Все регены от предметов"[].Sum()`

Comment: Конечный реген это вычисляемое, составное поле. Соответствнно, в обычном приложении C#, я бы сделал это через простое свойство. Это те что с get и set. Выше уже написали, образно, что там после return писать)